# Unable to run KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, airflow-2.x, kubernetespodoperator

I am using airflow 2.4.3 and running KubernetesPodOperator

Below is the code and error:-

Please help me with creating a KubernetesPosOperator in python. I have tried on both GCP and Azure.

Also adding the kubernetes documentation for reference:-

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_api/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod/index.html#airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod.KubernetesPodOperator

I can also share any other info if required.

```
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator

#custom modules
from spark_API.spark_submit import SparkSubmit

#import modules
import json
import datetime
import logging

import airflow_API
import time


airflow_dag_object = AirflowDagUtilities("aaa_test_airflow_api")


def def_func1(**kwargs):
    print("In func1")
    
    namespace = "segmentation-pipeline"
    docker_image = "****:v6" # name commented out
    is_delete_operator_pod = True
    
    docker_image_creds =  [k8s.V1LocalObjectReference("****")] # harbor name commented out

    
    submit_command = ["/bin/bash","-c"]
    
    max_cores = 60
    driver_memory = "4g"
    executor_memory = "4g"
            
    submit_args = "/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --master local[" + str(max_cores) + "] --driver-memory " + \
                                driver_memory + " --executor-memory " + executor_memory + " "
    
    submit_spark_pipeline_config_conf = "--conf " + '\'' + 'spark.pipelineConfig' + "=" + json.dumps(_infra_config.get_infra_config(),separators=(',',':')) + '\'' + " "
    
    submit_spark_broadcast_timeout = "--conf " + '\"' + "spark.sql.broadcastTimeout" + "=" + str("36000") + '\"' + " "
    
    submit_spark_max_result_size = "--conf " + '\"' + "spark.driver.maxResultSize" + "=" + str("0") + '\"' + " "

    final_dependency_jars = ["./resources/mysql_connector_java_5.1.45.jar",\
                            "./resources/commons_httpclient_3.0.1.jar"]
                 
    
    dependency_jars_string = ','.join(list(set(final_dependency_jars)))
    
    submit_spark_dependency_jars = "--conf " + '\"' + "spark.jars" + "=" + dependency_jars_string + '\"' + " "
    extra_conf = []
    extra_conf_final = []
    
    for conf in extra_conf:
        conf_appended_string = "--conf " + '\"' + conf + '\'' + " "
        extra_conf_final.append(conf_appended_string)
            
    
    extra_conf = " ".join(extra_conf_final) + " "
    
    airflow_task_settings = airflow_API.extract_airflow_task_details(kwargs['task_instance'])
    
    submit_spark_airflow_task_details = "--conf " + '\"' + "spark.airflowTaskDetails" + "=" + json.dumps(airflow_task_settings) + '\'' + " "
    
    common_submit_args_beginning = submit_args + submit_spark_broadcast_timeout + submit_spark_max_result_size + submit_spark_dependency_jars + extra_conf + submit_spark_airflow_task_details
    
    application_resource = "/update_scores.py"
    application_arguments = ["test_args"]
    
    string_application_arguments = " "
    for i in range(0,len(application_arguments)):
        string_application_arguments = string_application_arguments + " " + json.dumps(application_arguments[i]) 
    
    
    common_submit_args_end = application_resource + string_application_arguments
            
    platform_utilities = PlatformUtilities(_infra_config)
    
    print("platform_utilities.get_python_modules_path() -> ",str(platform_utilities.get_python_modules_path()))
    
    submit_spark_python_module_path = "--conf " + '\"' + "spark.modulePath" + "=" + str(platform_utilities.get_python_modules_path()) + '\"' + " "
    
    submit_spark_args = [common_submit_args_beginning + submit_spark_pipeline_config_conf + submit_spark_python_module_path + common_submit_args_end]
    
    print("submit_spark_args -> ",submit_spark_args)
    
    submit_in_cluster = True
    
       
    submit_spark_pod_affinity = k8s.V1Affinity(
    node_affinity=k8s.V1NodeAffinity(k8s.V1NodeSelectorTerm(
                    match_expressions=[
                        k8s.V1NodeSelectorRequirement(key="****", operator="In", values=["n2-highmem-8"]),
                        k8s.V1NodeSelectorRequirement(key="deployment", operator="In", values=["dynamic"]),
                    ]
                )
            )
        )
    
    
    submit_spark_pod_tolerations = [k8s.V1Toleration(key="deployment", operator="Equal", value="dynamic", effect="NoSchedule")]
    
    application_name = "test_airflow_api_test_task_id"
    
    container_resources = k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
                requests={
                    'memory': str("10Gi"),
                    'cpu': str("2")
                },
                limits={
                    'memory': str("50Gi"),
                    'cpu': str("5")
                }
            )
    
    submit_startup_timeout_seconds = 600
    
    submit_get_logs = True
    
    kube_submssion = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace = namespace,
                    image = docker_image,
                    is_delete_operator_pod = is_delete_operator_pod,
                    image_pull_secrets = docker_image_creds,
                    cmds = submit_command,
                    arguments = submit_spark_args,
                    in_cluster = submit_in_cluster,
                    affinity = submit_spark_pod_affinity,
                    tolerations = submit_spark_pod_tolerations,
                    container_resources = container_resources,
                    name = application_name,
                    task_id = application_name,
                    startup_timeout_seconds = submit_startup_timeout_seconds,
                    get_logs = submit_get_logs
                )
    
    kube_submssion.execute(context = None)
    
  

def def_func2(**kwargs):
    print("In func2")

dag_base = airflow_dag_object.get_dag_object()

func1=PythonOperator(
    task_id='func1',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=def_func1,
    dag=dag_base
)

func2=PythonOperator(
    task_id='func2',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=def_func2,
    dag=dag_base
)

func1 >> func2
```

OUTPUT ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 419, in execute
    context=context,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 387, in get_or_create_pod
    pod = self.find_pod(self.namespace or pod_request_obj.metadata.namespace, context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.py", line 371, in find_pod
    label_selector=label_selector,
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 15697, in list_namespaced_pod
    return self.list_namespaced_pod_with_http_info(namespace, **kwargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 15826, in list_namespaced_pod_with_http_info
    collection_formats=collection_formats)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 353, in call_api
    _preload_content, _request_timeout, _host)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 184, in __call_api
    _request_timeout=_request_timeout)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 377, in request
    headers=headers)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 244, in GET
    query_params=query_params)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 234, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (400)
Reason: Bad Request
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '6ab39ea1-f955-4481-b3eb-7b3abe747a7c', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '8e487991-120d-49d0-940a-ace0b0e64421', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': '8f6ab0b3-abdf-4782-994c-2f0f247592d2', 'Date': 'Thu, 12 Jan 2023 13:13:20 GMT', 'Content-Length': '169'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"found ',', expected: !, identifier, or 'end of string'","reason":"BadRequest","code":400}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous version of **airflow < 2.3** **KubernetesPodOperator** used to work with **None** context

As mentioned in your question

```
kube_submssion = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace = namespace,
                    image = docker_image,
                    is_delete_operator_pod = is_delete_operator_pod,
                    image_pull_secrets = docker_image_creds,
                    cmds = submit_command,
                    arguments = submit_spark_args,
                    in_cluster = submit_in_cluster,
                    affinity = submit_spark_pod_affinity,
                    tolerations = submit_spark_pod_tolerations,
                    container_resources = container_resources,
                    name = application_name,
                    task_id = application_name,
                    startup_timeout_seconds = submit_startup_timeout_seconds,
                    get_logs = submit_get_logs
                )
    
kube_submssion.execute(context = None)
```

The execute method is expecting the context as mentioned in the documentation at followig link

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/cncf/kubernetes/operators/kubernetes_pod.html#KubernetesPodOperator.execute

You can pass the context from ****kwargs** to the execute method. You can try by passing `kwargs` to `execute` method

```
kube_submssion.execute(context = kwargs)
```